# Use R to calculate cohen's Kappa for a categorical rating but within a range of tolerance?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a series of ratings (categorical with at least 12 levels) from 2 independent raters. I would like to calculate inter-rater reliability, but allowing for a difference of one level. I.e. Level 1 and level 2 would be considered agreement, but level 1 and level 3 would not. I don't want to use a measure like a correlation coefficient, because it's important to know if the ratings are within 1 level of difference or not. Can this be done?

*edit to include sample data: each cell represents the number of raters (max=2) assigning a rating of A-E*

`structure(list(A = c(2, 2, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0), B = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,2), C = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0), D=c(0,0,2,0,0,2,1,0,0), E=c(0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0)),row.names = c(NA,9L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Could you post some example data?

Comment: yes, sorry about that. The original post has been edited to include sample data. Each row is a different case, each column is a given rating, and each cell is the number of raters who assigned that rating. I would like to be able to measure concordance with zero levels of difference (e.g. row 1), i.e. a traditional cohen's kappa, or concordance within 1 level of difference (e.g. row 5). Thanks!

Comment: Is your data in the format that you gave for the sample? Basically, I think this would be much easier if you have the data in two columns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I'm not sure if this will work for you, but I think it will hit the mark. Basically, you need to find agreement between raters under different criteria of agreement. That's really not that big of a deal. Basically, either the raters agree, or they don't, for the purposes of Cohen's kappa.

Start off by making your sample data:

```
testdata <- structure(list(A=c(2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                           B=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,2),
                           C=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0),
                           D=c(0,0,2,0,0,2,1,0,0),
                           E=c(0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0)),
            row.names = c(NA,9L),
            class = "data.frame")
```

For the calculation of kappa, we'll use the `irr` package:

```
library(irr)
```

The `kappa2` function in `irr` takes a 2*n data frame or matrix and returns the calculation. Your data is in a different format, so we need to convert it to something that `kappa2` can handle. If you have it in this format already, it will be much easier.

First, I start by creating a new data frame to receive the restructured results.

```
new_testdata <- data.frame(R1="",R2="",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Now, a simple loop goes to each row and returns a vector with the ratings by each rater. Obviously, this isn't the actual ratings that were assigned; the code here just assumes that the first rater always rated higher than the second rater. It doesn't matter in this particular case since we are only concerned with agreement, but I do hope you have the full data.

```
for(x in 1:dim(testdata)[1]) {
    new_testdata <- rbind(new_testdata,rep(names(testdata),testdata[x,]))
}
rm(x)
new_testdata <- new_testdata[-1,] # Drop first, empty column
```

Now, we can obtain the regular kappa.

```
kappa2(ratings=new_testdata)

  Cohen's Kappa for 2 Raters (Weights: unweighted)

  Subjects = 9
  Raters = 2
  Kappa = 0.723

  z = 4.56
  p-value = 5.23e-06
```

Now, you want to have a different kappa where one level of disagreement isn't scored as an issue. That's no problem; basically, what you need to do is convert what is in `new_testdata` into a binary representation of agreement or disagreement. It should not affect the kappa in this case. (It will, however, affect the kappa if your raters have only two levels to choose from; this will artificially cap the value).

To start, let's create a table that converts letters to numbers. This will make our life easier.

```
convtable <- data.frame(old=c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                        new=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                        stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Now, we can use it to convert the values in new_testdata to numeric representations.

```
new_testdata$R1 <- convtable$new[match(new_testdata$R1,convtable$old)]
new_testdata$R2 <- convtable$new[match(new_testdata$R2,convtable$old)]
```

We can easily check for agreement by just taking the difference between the two columns.

```
new_testdata$diff <- abs(new_testdata$R1-new_testdata$R2)
```

Then, just recode R1 and R2 to be 1 and 1 for places that meet your agreement criteria (less than or equal to one level of difference between the two ratings), and 1 and 0 (or 0 and 1) otherwise.

```
new_testdata[new_testdata$diff<=1,c("R1","R2")] <- c(1,1)
new_testdata[new_testdata$diff>1,c("R1","R2")] <- c(1,0)
new_testdata <- new_testdata[1:2]              # Drop the difference variable
```

Now, just run your kappa again.

```
kappa2(ratings=new_testdata)

  Cohen's Kappa for 2 Raters (Weights: unweighted)

  Subjects = 9
  Raters = 2
  Kappa = 0

  z = NaN
  p-value = NaN
```

Whoa, what happened? Well, the data that you gave me was basically fully concordant when using agreement as +/- 1 level. There are some [methodological issues that can occur when](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/can-one-use-cohens-kappa-for-two-judgements-only) performing kappa on a binary response variable, as shown in the CrossValidated post I linked. If your data is less "uniform" than the sample data, you should get a real kappa value and not an anomalous zero like that one. However, that's more of a methods question, and you may need to ask a follow-up over on CrossValidated.

Comment: Looking at the code, this is phenomenal and should answer my question. The data I gave was made up, so yes, it would be fully concordant according to the criteria. The actual data is two columns of ratings, but I didn't know how to put that in a usable form on this forum. I'll look at it and let you know if it solves my problem. Thanks again!

Comment: This seems to do the trick! I don't know methodologically whether this is a kosher way to assess concordance in this way, but operationally, it solves my problem. Thanks again.